# Compare two arrays and remove items with partial match

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, compare

I need to compare two arrays for PARTIAL / SUBSTRING matches. If these are found, I want the matching items removed from the originalArray or create a new array with all those items that did not have a partial match,

```
var originalArray = ['www.google.com/opq', 'www.yelp.com/abc', 'www.yahoo.com/klm', 'www.bing.com/xyz', 'www.google.com/124'];

var itemsToBeRemoved = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com'];

// DESIRED ARRAY: An array with items that did not have a partial match. For example: 
var cleanArray = ['www.yelp.com/abc', 'www.bing.com/xyz']
```

It work when its a FULL / EXACT match.
But it is NOT what I need.

```
function cleanFullMatch(){ 
// Your main array  
var originalArray = ['www.google.com/rugby', 'www.yelp.com/abc', 'www.yahoo.com/tennis', 'www.bing.com/xyz', 'www.google.com/football']; 
Logger.log(originalArray);
    
// This array contains strings that needs to be removed from main array 
var itemsToBeRemoved = ['www.google.com/rugby', 'www.yahoo.com/tennis', 'www.google.com/football'];

var cleanObj = {};
itemsToBeRemoved.forEach( e => cleanObj[e] = true); 
itemsToBeRemoved.forEach( e => itemsToBeRemoved[e]= true);
    
var cleanArray = originalArray.filter(function(val){   return !cleanObj [val] })
Logger.log(cleanArray);
}
```

Comment: Use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript RegExp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_constructor.asp) to create regular expression and [array.filter(function)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) to remove elements that does not match the regex.

Sample Code:

```js
function cleanFullMatch(){ 
  // Your main array  
  var originalArray = ['www.google.com/rugby', 'www.yelp.com/abc', 'www.yahoo.com/tennis', 'www.bing.com/xyz', 'www.google.com/football']; 
  Logger.log(originalArray);
  
  // This array contains strings that needs to be removed from main array 
  var itemsToBeRemoved = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'google.com'];
  
  // loop through itemsToBeRemove
  itemsToBeRemoved.forEach(function(rgx){
    
    // convert each element of itemsToBeRemove to regular expression
    var re = new RegExp(rgx);
    
    // filter the array by removing the elements that match the regex
    // test() method checks if the string matches the regex
    originalArray = originalArray.filter( word => !re.test(word));
  });
  
  Logger.log(originalArray);
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works very well as well. I can myself using the "new RegExp" in other scenarios as well.

Answer (score 1):

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the elements of the `originalArray` so that none of the `itemsToBeRemoved` is present in any of the filtered elements.

There are many ways to check whether a substring is included in another string, as others said, like [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

You could then iterate through all of these `itemsToBeRemoved` in different ways. You could, for example, use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function cleanFullMatch(){ 
  var originalArray = ['www.google.com/rugby', 'www.yelp.com/abc', 'www.yahoo.com/tennis', 'www.bing.com/xyz', 'www.google.com/football']; 
  var itemsToBeRemoved = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
  var cleanArray = originalArray.filter(element => !itemsToBeRemoved.some(item => element.includes(item)));
  console.log(cleanArray);
}
```

Or, alternatively, [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var cleanArray = originalArray.filter(element => itemsToBeRemoved.every(item => !element.includes(item)));
```

As you can see, the filtering process can be reduced to a single line.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly! And in a single line of code... some much to learn...